# Oracle Grouping last 24 hours by 2 hours interval without gaps

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, group-by

I would like to write a query that `group amount field` every 2 hours for the last 24 hours. Hours without amount should return zero.

Contents of `Amounts` table :

```
 input_date          | amount  
------------------------------
 29/07/2015-11:03:00 | 100  
 29/07/2015-10:45:02 | 100  
 29/07/2015-08:22:57 | 100  
 29/07/2015-06:50:45 | 12000   
 28/07/2015-22:16:48 | 235
```

When `SYSDATE` is `29/07/2015-11:05`, expected result should be

```
 date                | sum
-----------------------------
 29/07/2015-10:00:00 | 200  
 29/07/2015-08:00:00 | 100  
 29/07/2015-06:00:00 | 12000  
 29/07/2015-04:00:00 | 0  
 29/07/2015-02:00:00 | 0  
 29/07/2015-00:00:00 | 0  
 28/07/2015-22:00:00 | 235    
 29/07/2015-20:20:00 | 0  
 29/07/2015-18:00:00 | 0  
 29/07/2015-16:00:00 | 0  
 29/07/2015-14:00:00 | 0  
 29/07/2015-12:00:00 | 0
```

Comment: OK, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/19af5/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE data (
 input_date,
 amount
) AS
          SELECT TO_DATE( '29/09/2015-11:03:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY-HH24:MI:SS' ), 100 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_DATE( '29/09/2015-10:45:02', 'DD/MM/YYYY-HH24:MI:SS' ), 100 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_DATE( '29/09/2015-08:22:57', 'DD/MM/YYYY-HH24:MI:SS' ), 100 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_DATE( '29/09/2015-06:50:45', 'DD/MM/YYYY-HH24:MI:SS' ), 12000 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_DATE( '28/09/2015-22:16:48', 'DD/MM/YYYY-HH24:MI:SS' ), 235 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH two_hour_windows ( time ) AS (
  SELECT     TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'HH24' ) - ( LEVEL * 2 - 2 + MOD( TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'HH24' ), 2 ) )/24
  FROM       DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12
)
SELECT time,
       COALESCE( SUM( amount ), 0 ) AS total_amount
FROM   two_hour_windows t
       LEFT OUTER JOIN data d
       ON ( time <= input_date AND input_date < time + 1/12 )
GROUP BY time
ORDER BY time
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/19af5/1/0)**:

```
|                        TIME | TOTAL_AMOUNT |
|-----------------------------|--------------|
| September, 28 2015 16:00:00 |            0 |
| September, 28 2015 18:00:00 |            0 |
| September, 28 2015 20:00:00 |            0 |
| September, 28 2015 22:00:00 |          235 |
| September, 29 2015 00:00:00 |            0 |
| September, 29 2015 02:00:00 |            0 |
| September, 29 2015 04:00:00 |            0 |
| September, 29 2015 06:00:00 |        12000 |
| September, 29 2015 08:00:00 |          100 |
| September, 29 2015 10:00:00 |          200 |
| September, 29 2015 12:00:00 |            0 |
| September, 29 2015 14:00:00 |            0 |
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for a 1 hour interval.I'm not shure how to round it for 2 hours.

```
SELECT times1.input_date,NVL(docs.amount,0) amount   
FROM   
(SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(input_date, 'HH'),'yyyymmddhh24') input_date, SUM(amount)   amount   
 FROM amounts  
 WHERE (input_date >= sysdate- TO_CHAR( 24 ) /24 )   
 GROUP BY TRUNC(input_date, 'HH')   
 ) docs  
 RIGHT OUTER JOIN   
 (select TO_CHAR(ROUND(sysdate, 'HH')- rownum/24,'yyyymmddhh24') input_date, 0 amount  
  from all_objects   
  where rownum <=  TO_CHAR( 24 )  
 ) times1  
 ON (docs.input_date = times1.input_date)  
 ORDER BY times1.input_date DESC;
```